# Mysql empty only one selected column

Tags: mysql

In mysql I have a table called requests. The table looking like this

```
 ==================
 |    requests      |
  ==================
  +  id             +
  +  date           +
  +  firstname      +
  +  lastname       +
  +  request_number +
  +  status         +
  +++++++++++++++++++
```

Now here I want that on single button click I will delete all the values stored inside `request_number` and the `request_number` column will be only empty.It will not delete the column name

Comment: `UPDATE requests SET request_number = '';` (or `...SET request_number = 0;` or `...SET request_number = NULL;`), whatever you mean with "empty".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to empty request_number cells in entire table

```
UPDATE requests SET request_number = NULL;
```

If you need to empty request_number for records having specif condition

```
UPDATE requests SET request_number = NULL where <your condition>;
```